# WSO2 Identity Server Concept of Users

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I am new to WSO2 Identity Server and what I intend to use it for user creation, authentication and authorization for microservices(4 micro-services). However, I am struggling to grab the concept of users. My understanding is we have two user groups: users who have access to the identity server and users you create for your application. I don't know if I right with that. If that is the case how do I create users for my micro-services and users who can access the identity server?

Answer (score 0):

Like you mentioned, in the WSO2 Identity Server we can maintain two types of users

1. Users who perform administrative or development tasks (Privileged users)
2. Users who consume your applications eg who uses WSO2 IS to authenticate to  the applications (End users of your Business)

For both types of users onboarding flow is the same (check [1]). The main difference is Privileged users(type-1 users) will have roles with advanced permissions & end-users (type-2) won't have that kind of roles.

Eg: If we want to use WSO2 Identity Server for employee IAM for organization, we can consider all the employees as users. Here most of them would be end users but infrateam/IT team will be considered as privileged users as they have to maintain or perform develop tasks in WSO2 Identity Server.

For better management, we can have privileged users in one user store and endusers in another userstore. Eg based on users store, it is easier to write adaptive scripts to restrict privileged users from login to business applications or SCIM API to list down only privileged users.

[1]https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/adding-users-and-roles/

Comment: Thanks for this. Concerning the tip for better management which type of users should be placed in the primary and secondary user stores. For example if your company is developing an application to be used by external users. Which store do you keep your employees and the external users of the  application.